# How to associate code with a checkbox in an Outlook template?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created an Outlook template with checkboxes included. I want to display a message when a checkbox has been ticked. I have written some basic codes (msgbox etc.) related to each checkbox.

Issue:
**How** can I include/integrate my codes in the Outlook template?

Comment: Where and how did you create check boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to create a new custom Outlook form with a code behind. You can read more about that in the [Create an Outlook Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/outlook-forms/create-an-outlook-form) article.

You will not be able to achieve the required functionality with a message body. Any scripts from message bodies can't be run for security matters.